# How can I print 2 arrays with different values in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print 2 different arrays, One array has the name of the file and the other array has the content of the csv file.

First I am reading the contents of the given file through the path and then putting the content of the .csv file into an array which is `nextLine[]`

```
public static void fileRead(File file) throws IOException, CsvException {

        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader(file)).withSkipLines(1).build();
        String[] nextLine;
        File folder = new File("src/main/resources/FolderDocumentsToRead");
        String[] fileList = folder.list();

        while((nextLine = csvReader.readNext())!=null){
            System.out.println("Name of file: "+fileList[0]+", Title of Text: "+nextLine[0]);
        }
    }

}
```

The output I am trying to get is meant to look like;

`Name of file: ATale.csv, Title of Text: A TALE OF THE RAGGED MOUNTAINS`

`Name of file: Diggling.csv, Title of Text: DIDDLING`

The output I am getting looks like;

`Name of file: ATale.csv, Title of Text: A TALE OF THE RAGGED MOUNTAINS`

`Name of file: ATale.csv, Title of Text: DIDDLING`

I have tried using loops to get to the correct solution but I was just getting errors thrown at me and having a hard time with them.

I'm fairly new to using arrays and java in general, any tips would be appreciated even a tip towards getting the solution.

P.S first time using Stack overflow ahaha

Comment: The first thing that stood out to me was the literal value of 0 in the indecies. Should that be dynamic as you read it or is it always supposed to be set at 0?

Comment: The 0 gets the first value of the array, I'm assuming that's what you're asking. It is getting the first name of the file. @KemperLee

Comment: As it is, the String array is being redeclared each time through the loop, so index 0 will print the most recent entry for nextLine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the while loop, if you create a variable to keep track of the selected index then you will be able to modify it and have the change stay after the loop has finished.

```
    int index = 0;
    while(csvReader.hasNext())
    {
        String fileName = fileList[index];
        String title = nextLine[index];
        index++;
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
    while((nextLine = csvReader.readNext())!=null)
```

can be/should be rewritten like so:

```
    while(csvReader.hasNext())
    {
        nextLine = csvReader.readNext();
        ...
    }
```

This helps a lot with reading/debugging

**NOTE** this is not any sort of solution but a recommendation for ease-of-use

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'll implement this now :)